# When I activated "Emergency Services," how to stop the 911 call?

Tags: iphone

I live alone. I very rarely have episodes, but I lose center of gravity, get double vision, fall, and have trouble talking. The last thing I want is anyone to dial 911. I just need to wait it out, relax, and take Ativan.

I've got medical friends listed on my Emergency Services that will come to my aid. Based on experience I do not want any EMTs involved and then a trip to the ER.

How can I hold the power button, have people I registered come, but not EMTs?

Today Siri saved me and made the call, double vision means no address book...

How can I hold power button to inform friends I need help without involving EMTs?

Comment: This is not an answer because I don't have any experience with trying to set up an iPhone this way, but one option might be to have a phone with no SIM card/cellular service, if it can be configured to message your emergency contacts via other means. There is also probably a solution involving jailbreaking your phone, albeit with all the negative aspects that entails.

Comment: Out of the scope of the answer as is -

Comment: What is Ativan?

Comment: @Clockwork: A brand name for [lorazepam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorazepam).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In short, you can’t reconfigure SOS to *not* contact your local emergency services.  This is by design and hard coded into your phone.

However, you can set up an Accessibility shortcut triggered by either a double or triple tap of the back of the phone.  This will trigger an action like sending out a text message to a group of people that you need assistance.

You can find the “Back Tap” under *Settings → Accessibility → Touch → Back Tap*

You will find a number of actions under Double and Triple Tap.  However, you’ll need to create a simple shortcut for this:

1. Create a new shortuct
2. Select “Get Current Location”. Be certain to allow the app to use your *precise* location
3. Select “Send a Message” Action.  Enter your text and add the “Current Location” variable.
4. Type a short canned message:  “I’ve crashed into the sofa, send beer!”
5. Enter your receipients
6. Save and attach to Accessibility Shortcut (see above)

[image: Send Help Shortcut w/ Location]

It’s a simple two action shortcut - it doesn’t need to be overly complex, but you can customize as necessary.  The beauty with a Shortcut like this is not only can you “attach” it to an action like double/triple tap, but you can use Siri to activiate it as well.

Comment: Great idea, however I found it relatively easy to accidentally activate the back tap shortcut. You may want to show a timed "cancel" button or some other kind of timeout-positive confirmation (if possible), othervise you may randomly alert your relatives whenever you drop your phone or accidentally tap your pocket.

Comment: @Neinstein "I found it relatively easy to accidentally activate the back tap shortcut" - You'll be getting a lot of beer.

Comment: @VanitySlug-codidact.com either that or turning into the boy who cried wolf